# Could not find symbol proccess, Node.js while trying to connect MongoDB with Windows Azure Mobile Services

Tags: node.js, mongodb, azure

I am trying to connect MongoDB with windows azure mobile service. I have created an API trying to write a script for POST method. I am getting an error in line

```
mongoose.connect(process.env.MongoConnectionString);
```

it says , could not find symbol proccess.

Please suggest me whats wrong and , if possible suggest a good tutorial to do this stuff.

I am following this codes right now [GITHUB](https://gist.github.com/sedouard/e8e291e57a88ea741663#file-azuremongoput-js)

Comment: Your additional question, regarding tutorial recommendations, is off-topic for StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried replacing process.env.MongoConnectionString with the actual connection string?

One way to store key/value pairs in Mobile Services is by using the Apps Settings section in the Configure tab.  You can retrieve it like this:

```
var config = require('mobileservice-config');
var mongoConString = config.appSettings.MongoConnectionString;
```

Answer (score 0):

To use MongoDB in mobile services, we can follow the [office guide](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-dotnet-backend-use-non-relational-data-store/). Whether in Node.js or .Net, the steps of creating operations are the same shown in the first section in this article.

@ [CSharpRocks](https://stackoverflow.com/users/793891/csharprocks) provided a way to get `appSettings` in Mobile Service.

Also, we can leverage ‘`request`’ object provide by Azure Mobile Service. Code snippets in a custom API:

`exports.get=function(req,res){
    // req.service.config.appSettings.MongoConnectionString
}`